# Wrap a command with two arguments inside an environment

Tags: environments

I know this question looks like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872951/wrap-latex-command-in-environment) but the solutions given there won't work for me.

I'm trying to replace the `\element{foo}{bar}` macro from automultiplechoice to get something like

```
\begin{qcm}{foo}
    bar
\end{qcm}
```

I have tried the environ package, the document compiles but the question defined this way is ignored when using `\restitutegroup`. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{automultiplechoice}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\NewEnviron{qcm}[1]{\element{#1}{\BODY}}
\begin{document}

\begin{qcm}{test}
  \begin{question}{foo}
    foo
  \end{question}
\end{qcm}

\element{test}{
   \begin{question}{bar}
     bar
   \end{question}
}

\begin{examcopy}[2]
    \insertgroup{test}
    \clearpage
\end{examcopy}
\end{document}
```

Only the question "bar" is restituted.

Any clue would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within an *environment*, the scope of definitions are local unless explicitly made `\global`. So, any definitions made within `qcm` may be void if not handled appropriately. This is the case with `\element` - it creates a token list whose definition (or contents) doesn't survive the group.

The example below makes the definition `\global`, as well as ensuring that `\BODY` survives the end of `qcm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
% https://github.com/bdemeshev/pr201/blob/master/prob_exams_collection/automultiplechoice.sty
\usepackage{automultiplechoice}

\NewEnviron{qcm}[1]{%
  \def\arg{#1}%
  \expandafter\element\expandafter\arg\expandafter{\BODY}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\element}[2]{%
  \AMC@prepare@element{#1}%
  \global\csname #1@\romannumeral\AMCtok@k\endcsname={#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{qcm}{test}
  \begin{question}{foo}
    foo
  \end{question}
\end{qcm}

\element{test}{%
   \begin{question}{bar}
     bar
   \end{question}
}

\begin{examcopy}[2]
  \insertgroup{test}
  \clearpage
\end{examcopy}

\end{document}
```